# Why Can't wp_editor Be Used in a Custom Widget?

Tags: widgets, wp-editor

I've been working on developing a plugin that adds a widget that allows you to edit the content with a wysiwyg editor. I want to use the default wordpress editor by calling `wp_editor()`. I've seen people say you can't do this, and sure enough, it crashes when you try to update the widget content.

Can anyone explain why `wp_editor()` can't be used in widgets?

I'm hoping to figure out how to get around that once I know why it doesn't work. However, Chrome doesn't spit out any errors in the console, so I'm not sure what's happening that it bugs out.

Thanks,
goldentoa11

Comment: Likely relevant: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19173

Comment: Way, way, way old question, but I've stumbled upon to this problem today. I highly recommend (for future references) to check out the existing plugin made by wordpress: [https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/aaf99e691391cfceb004d848450dbbf3344b1bee/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-text.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/aaf99e691391cfceb004d848450dbbf3344b1bee/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-text.php)

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: Because there is a hidden widget where the TinyMCE appears first.

Long answer (sorry, a very long answer):

Go to the [Codex and copy the example widget `Foo_Widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) to make sure we are talking about the same code. Now open your IDE (not an editor) and write a short testing widget as plugin. Starting with a minimal plugin header...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Widget Test Plugin
Description: Testing plugincode
*/
```

... adding the widget code from the codex and registering the widget with the `add_action()` call. Now modify the `form` method within the widget class as shown here:

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
        $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    }
    else {
        $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    }
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php

/*** add this code ***/
    $content   = 'Hello World!';
    $editor_id = 'widget_editor';

    $settings = array(
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'textarea_rows' => 3,
        'teeny'         => true,
    );

    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
/*** end editing ***/
}
```

Go to your blog, activate the plugin, go to the widget page and drag the `Foo Widget` into a sidebar. You will see it will fail.

Do you see the `Foo Widget` description on the left side? Do a right click on the description and choose 'Inspect' from your developer tools (you have some developer tools like FireBug or Chrome DevTools, huh? In FireFox you can also choose the build in 'Inspect Element'). Browse through the HTML code and you will see there is an editor wrap inside the 'hidden' widget.
[image: wp_editor in the hidden widget]

You can see one editor in the sidebar on the right and there is an editor in the 'hidden' widget on the left. This cannot work properly because TinyMCE don't know which editor should be used.

**What do we need?**

We need a **unique** ID for our editor.

```
/*** add this code ***/
    $rand    = rand( 0, 999 );
    $ed_id   = $this->get_field_id( 'wp_editor_' . $rand );
    $ed_name = $this->get_field_name( 'wp_editor_' . $rand );

    $content   = 'Hello World!';
    $editor_id = $ed_id;

      $settings = array(
      'media_buttons' => false,
      'textarea_rows' => 3,
      'textarea_name' => $ed_name,
      'teeny'         => true,
    );

    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
/*** end edit ***/
```

Modify the code within the `form` method again with the code above. We create a unique number with `rand()` and append this number to the `id` and `name` attributes. But stop, what about saving the values???

Go to the `update` method and add `die(var_dump($new_instance));` in the first line. If you press `Save` on the widget, the script will die and print out the submitted values. You will see there is a value like `wp_editor_528`. If you reload the page and save the widget again, the number will be changed to something else because it is a random number.

How will I know which random number was set in the widget? Simply send the random number with the widget data. Add this to the `form` method

```
printf(
  '<input type="hidden" id="%s" name="%s" value="%d" />',
  $this->get_field_id( 'the_random_number' ),
  $this->get_field_name( 'the_random_number' ),
  $rand
);
```

In the update routine, we can now access the random number with `$new_instance['the_random_number'];` and so we can access the editor content with

```
$rand = (int) $new_instance['the_random_number'];
$editor_content = $new_instance[ 'wp_editor_' . $rand ];
die(var_dump($editor_content));
```

As you can see, the editor content will be submitted and you can save it or do anything else with it.

**Caveat**

The editor content is only submitted correctly if the TinyMCE is **not** in visual mode (WYSIWYG mode). You have to switch to the text mode befor press 'Save'. Otherwise the predefined content (in this case `$content = 'Hello World!';`) is submitted. I don't now why, but there is a simple workaround for this.

Write a small jQuery script that triggers the click on the 'text' tab before saving the widget content.

JavaScript (saved as `widget_script.js` somewhere in your theme/plugin folders):

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($) {
        $( '.widget-control-save' ).click(
            function() {
                // grab the ID of the save button
                var saveID   = $( this ).attr( 'id' );

                // grab the 'global' ID
                var ID       = saveID.replace( /-savewidget/, '' );

                // create the ID for the random-number-input with global ID and input-ID
                var numberID = ID + '-the_random_number';

                // grab the value from input field
                var randNum  = $( '#'+numberID ).val();

                // create the ID for the text tab
                var textTab  = ID + '-wp_editor_' + randNum + '-html';

                // trigger a click
                $( '#'+textTab ).trigger( 'click' );

            }
        );
    }
);
```

And enqueue it

```
function widget_script(){

    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'widgets.php' === $pagenow )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'widget-script', plugins_url( 'widget_script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'widget_script' );
```

That's it. Easy, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer @Ralf912. I have spent the last couple of days trying to integrate a RTE inside a custom widget. This will be the basis for my final solution. For any new widget makers such as myself, the update portion of this answer will need to be modified to include variables and store the data. You can find examples of this happening in other widget examples. Thanks again!

Comment: Great Answer @Ralf912. WOW 

Answer (score 1):

do not know the exact answer why wp_editor() is not working inside of widgets, but widgets have some restrictions.

But wp_editor is only one of many possibilities to use the visual editor in the backend of WordPress. Try to initialize the visual editor with jQuery somehow. I do not think that you can do it inside the widget window itself, but a lightbox or something like that might help.

Here is a way to do it:

```
/**
 * Add TinyMCE to multiple Textareas (usually in backend).
 */
//  add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts','my_admin_print_footer_scripts',99);
function my_admin_print_footer_scripts() {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery(function($)
        {
            var i=1;
            $('.customEditor textarea').each(function(e)
            {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                if (!id)
                {
                    id = 'customEditor-' + i++;
                    $(this).attr('id',id);
                }

                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);

            });
        });
    /* ]]> */</script><?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible to accomplish tinyMCE in widget. In fact [it has been already done](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/black-studio-tinymce-widget). The reason why simply calling `wp_editor()` doesn't work in widget form is that form markup is asynchronously delivered using AJAX. Try [searching here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=tinymce%20ajax) for more details.