# Still desperate about multiple TinyMCEs in widgets - is there any good solution to this yet?

Tags: customization, widgets, templates, tinymce, wp-editor

In a project I have to use multiple tinyMCEs within a single widget. These widgets are also used within the Page Builder Plugin by Siteorigin.

However there is still a fundamental problem with `wp_editor()` used inside a widgets' `form()` function. There is no Javascript error, the editors are simply not loaded (as you see all the buttons are missing, no writing possible):

[image]

This problem has already extensivly been discussed four years ago, but none of those solutions seem to work for me nowadays ([Why Can't wp_editor Be Used in a Custom Widget?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82670/why-cant-wp-editor-be-used-in-a-custom-widget)).

Do you know a solution how to use multiple `wp_editor()` inside a widget or how to use multiple tinyMCEs inside a custom widget? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To use it in a widget you need to use the Javascript editor API introduced in 4.8: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/20/editor-api-changes-in-4-8/

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks a lot I will have a closer look on that!