# Multiple Tinymce/wp_editor in WordPress >4.8

Tags: customization, tinymce

I'm struggling for two days and started here with success:
[Why Can't wp_editor Be Used in a Custom Widget?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82670/why-cant-wp-editor-be-used-in-a-custom-widget)

I managed to have multiple TMCE on one page (displayed by a widget); all save data correctly. When i assign (as required) *different* IDs to each textfield, i get an upon clicking on the "visual" button (activating tmce):

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onpageload' of undefined'

When I assign a static ID to each textfield, the error is gone, but only the first textfield will get transformed to a tmce; the others remain regular textareas, no error.

I understand why the latter happens. I don't understand the error in first place, this is the resulting code, with a single tmce:

```
<textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="30" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="widgets[c29][wp_editor]" id="widget-bo_widget_rte-c29-wp_editor">this is text</textarea>
```

Im pretty sure this works in WP <4.8, since it uses TinyMCE <4 (??), but I can not find a solution for > 4.8

Answer (score 1):

After three days i found a solution, many others are seeking (dozends of unanswered threads here and there) *wp_editor() does not work in WP >4.8*

Instead, use wp.editor Javascript-API: https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.editor